# How to redirect upper case URL to lower case Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

We have a strange issue in Magento2.

All the URL on our website are accessible both by Upper case and Lower case. For example: http://www.example.com/sweatshirts is also accessible by http://www.example.com/SWEATSHIRTS

Our SEO team recommends that the URL accessible with UPPERCASE should be 301 redirected to lower case.

Can any one please guide me on how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can just create a custom  URL rewrite from the backend under **Marketing > URL Rewrites** and click the button Add URL rewrite.

- request path should be the uppercase path
- target path should be the lowercase path
- choose 301 redirect in the redirect dropdown

Unfortunately if you have a lot of categories this is gonna be painful.

Going the .htaccess way if you're on Apache is probably better

Comment: Custom URL is an option if you we have few URL certainly not with 20K URL's. Also, I wonder if this is a bug or a feature in Magento2 as Magento1 used to do 404

Answer (score 0):

Using the Magento URL redirect method (suggested above) returns an error when attempting to do a redirect of uppercase to lowercase or vice versa: "Request Path for Specified Store already exists."  We have had to use an entry in the main .htaccess of the Magento installation as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /SWEATSHIRT /sweatshirt
Redirect /Sweatshirt /sweatshirt
```